# How many variables can logistic regression handle?

Tags: logistic, feature-selection, high-dimensional

Not from a theoretical point of view, but from a practical one: is there a point at which there are "too many" predictors for a logistic regression model to perform well?

For larger datasets (with more columns) I have always used machine learning methods that I know can handle dozens or hundreds of variables. However, I've never tried something like that with logistic regression.

**My hypothesis:** I'm guessing that the issue is that multicollinearity is more of a problem for logistic regression than it is for other methods, and with dozens or hundreds of variables, multicollinearity will be inevitable.

**My Question:** From your experience, approximately how many variables can logistic regression effectively handle?

**Follow up**: If my hypothesis is right and multicollinearity is the only limiting issue/factor, could logistic regression effectively handle 100 variables, given they are orthogonal?

Comment: Why would multicollinearity be a problem?  Standard regression routines handle even *exact* collinearity just fine.  There is no difference between logistic regression and any other linear regression model in this regard.  You can find plenty of posts here on CV describing successful applications of logistic regression to much larger problems than 100 variables.

Comment: @whuber Doesn't multicollinearity cause unstable predictions and huge confidence intervals in standard linear regression? And presumably the same in logistic regression?

Comment: @whuber I'm a bit rusty on this, but isn't there an actual performance reason we look at VIFs to try to slim down our OLS regression models? I thought it was because it caused unstable predictions and for that reason, wasn't "good practice" to dump a lot of collinear variables into the model.

Comment: No: it does not cause *predictions* to be unstable.  It can cause *parameter estimates* to be unstable--but that's an entirely different thing.  As far as practicality goes, I just ran a logistic regression with a thousand variables.  It took 10 seconds in `R`: `d <- 1e3; n <- 5*d; X <- cbind(y = sample.int(2, n, replace=TRUE)-1, as.data.frame(matrix(runif(d*n), n)));
fit <- glm(y ~ ., X, family=binomial)`

Comment: The problem with your second comment is that *multicollinearity* tells you *absolutely nothing* about how the variables might be related to the response.  It is at least theoretically possible that the variable you would most want to drop due to collinearity is the *only* one related to the response!  That's why IMHO all discussions of regression that focus solely on the explanatory variables are misguided.

Comment: @whuber Ahhh I see. So you're saying that the *only* issue multicollinearity causes for these standard regression models is parameter instability, which might cause issues for coefficient interpretation but not for predictive stability/accuracy. Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: Yes.  There is another practical issue with logistic regression and other GLMs compared to least squares regression: they may have trouble finding any solution at all in the presence of great amounts of multicollinearity.  That's a problem with their algorithms and the limitations of double precision floating point arithmetic.